# Redirect .do URL to a .action URL?

Tags: struts2, struts, web.xml

I migrated a struts1 page to struts2 in an application. However, I still need the old page's URL of "/login.do" to be accessible for backwards compatibility.

How can I redirect/map the "login.do" URL to "login.action"?

I believe that this can be accomplished by writing a filter class, but I don't want to do that because it seems too complicated for the task. There has to be a way to do it in web.xml, struts.xml or struts-config.xml.

I'll buy the person with best answer a beer (in Phoenix). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the action extension. This is from the [default `struts.properties`](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/strutsproperties.html):

```
### Used by the DefaultActionMapper
### You may provide a comma separated list, e.g. struts.action.extension=action,jnlp,do
### The blank extension allows you to match directory listings as well as pure action names
### without interfering with static resources, which can be specified as an empty string
### prior to a comma e.g. struts.action.extension=, or struts.action.extension=x,y,z,,
struts.action.extension=action,,
```

XML configuration of constants is preferred, however, so I'd put it in your `struts.xml`.

It also avoids an actual redirect, although a filter for that is trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dave. I forgot to mention that the application is currently being migrated to struts2 and adding the .do action extension to the configuration for struts2 causes all of the struts1 implementations to fail. There will be struts1 code in use for the foreseeable future. I guess I'll have to use a filter class.

Comment: @user1438547 Or redirect/forward from S1 actions when they're replaced, etc.